# wordpress Order a query by meta_value and then by post_date

Tags: wordpress, date

I'm using the following query (mytheme/function.php) to sort posts by Custom Field(=admin_rate)

```
function sort_searchresult_by_admin_rate($k) {
if (!is_home()) {
$k->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'admin_rate';
$k->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
$k->query_vars['order'] = 'DESC';
}
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','sort_searchresult_by_admin_rate');
```

For example I have 4 posts:

```
Title1  admin_rate=3    post_date=25 February 2014
Title2  admin_rate=4    post_date=26 February 2014
Title3  admin_rate=1    post_date=27 February 2014
Title4  admin_rate=1    post_date=28 February 2014
```

with sort_searchresult_by_admin_rate($k), I get the following results:

```
Title2  admin_rate=4    post_date=26 February 2014 (GOOD!)
Title1  admin_rate=3    post_date=25 February 2014 (GOOD!)
Title3  admin_rate=1    post_date=27 February 2014 (BAD!)
Title4  admin_rate=1    post_date=28 February 2014 (BAD!)
```

I want to Order posts by meta_value and then by date DESC same as:

```
Title2  admin_rate=4    post_date=26 February 2014 (GOOD!)
Title1  admin_rate=3    post_date=25 February 2014 (GOOD!)
Title4  admin_rate=1    post_date=28 February 2014 (GOOD!)
Title3  admin_rate=1    post_date=27 February 2014 (GOOD!)
```

is there a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple orderby values. Try the following:

```
$k->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value date';
```

Comment: `meta_value date`  gives this results:  Title4 ... Title3 ... Title2 ... Title1 ... (BAD!)